# Existence of solution to a system of Fredholm integral equations

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

Consider the following system of Fredholm integral equations with constant kernel matrix
$$
f(x)=K(x)\int_{0}^{1}f(s)ds
$$
where $K(x)\in C([0,1];M_{2\times 2}(%
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
)).$
For the scalar case, it is known by the Fredholm alternative that the above equation has a unique solution equals to zero if and only if $K(x)$ is different from $1$ for any $x\in [0,1]$.

My question is: What happens in the system case?. How I can check the spectrum condtion?.
Thank you in advance.